# SQL Trigger - Replace system user with custom field

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a sql trigger that is used to audit my database tables. 
Data is changed via web interface. Only authenticated users can change/add data.

In the trigger I have a line of code that says

```
select @UserName = system_user
```

Instead of the `system_user`, I want `UserId` (of authenticated web user) to be assigned to `@UserName`.
UserId is found in the table for every row as one of the columns.

What can I replace system_user with to get this effect. thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us what database (RDBMS) you are using.

Comment: That looks like SQL Server. Is that correct? If so which version? Also what are you asking exactly? How to look up stuff in tables and assign it to a variable?

Comment: @Martin - Yes pretty much that is my question. and I am using 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is SQL server, you can simply query from the "Inserted" table like below:

```
select @UserName =(select Your_USERID_ColumnName from inserted)
```

With SQL Server while inserts/updates and deletes happen there are two virtual tables "Inserted" and "Deleted" that you can query against

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am getting the following errorMsg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tblXXXXX_ChangeTracking, Line 77
Invalid column name 'UserId'. This is message for every table I am running this trigger against. And I can see UserId as a column in every table.

Comment: is the UserId part of the insert statement?